# How do I configure cargo to build projects to a specific directory?

Tags: plugins, rust, rust-cargo

I am creating an application that will allow plugins to add/modify features. For now it is cli application with multiple plugins for the data backends. Each plugin is implemented as a different project in a cargo workspace. How do I configure cargo or the package manifest to build the library project into a subdirectory where the output directory of the build is found?

Comment: Are you asking to change the output directory of build artifacts? If so, there's [The Cargo Book, "Output Options"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html#output-options).

Answer (score 2):

A small correction to @Fabian's answer, we need to add the following config to `.cargo/config.toml` folder in your **rust project's folder** or in your **home folder**.

```ini
[build]
target-dir = "/some/directory/rust-builds"
```

You can also add other configuration which are mentioned here - https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[build]
target-dir = "/desired/path" # path of where to place all generated artifacts
```

Source: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html

Also read: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-build.html#output-options

Comment: This answer does not work as of 12/1/22

Comment: Would it only put final binary there? or all intermediary stuff as well? like object files and dependecy crates and so on